# In what order are locations searched to load referenced DLLs?

Tags: .net, dll

I know that the .NET framework looks for referenced DLLs in several locations

- Global assembly cache (GAC)
- Any private paths added to the AppDomain
- The current directory of the executing assembly

What order are those locations searched? Is the search for a DLL ceased if a match is found or does it continue through all locations (and if so, how are conflicts resolved)?

*Also, please confirm or deny those locations and provide any other locations I have failed to mention.*

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Assembly loading is a rather elaborate process which depends on lots of different factors like configuration files, publisher policies, appdomain settings, CLR hosts, partial or full assembly names, etc.

The simple version is that the GAC is first, then the private paths. %PATH% is never used.

It is best to use [Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fuslogvw.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) to debug any assembly loading problems.

**EDIT**
[How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies) explains the process in more detail.

Comment: I am not having any real assembly loading problems. I am trying to understand the search/load order from an academic perspective.

Comment: And you're right about '%path%'... I had mistaken this from some work with p/invoke calls (I used '%path%' to simplify the 'DllImportAttribute' use).

Comment: If a .net dll references a native dll the paths could be used

Answer (score 7):

I found [an article](http://nerddawg.blogspot.com/2005/11/dll-search-order-during-loading.html) referencing the MSDN article on [DLL search order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586.aspx) that says

> For managed code dependencies, the
>   Global Assembly Cache always prevails;
>   the local assembly in application
>   directory will not be picked up if
>   there is an existing (or newer with
>   policy) copy in the GAC.

Considering this, I guess the MSDN list is correct with one addition

```
0. Global assembly cache
```

Answer (score 2):

> No longer is the current directory searched first when loading DLLs! This change was also made in Windows XP SP1. The default behavior now is to look in all the system locations first, then the current directory, and finally any user-defined paths.

(ref. http://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/archive/2003/06/24/9214.aspx)

The default search order, which can be changed by the application, is also described on MSDN: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order).

Comment: This seems to be dependant on loading a regular Dll not a .net assembly.