# Load the type of an unreferenced assembly within an object list

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I want to get a type from an unreferenced assembly. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/463366/1384848) to solve my problem.

The problem now is, that I'm loading the type `ObjectList` which contains another type from another assembly. I do it like this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom ("@c:\myAssemblies\myAssembly.Data.DomainObjects.dll");
Type myType = assembly.GetType ("myAssembly.Data.DomainObjects.ObjectList`1[[myAssembly.otherNamespace.myClass, myAssembly.otherNamespace, Version=1.13.73.1082, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fee00910d6e5f53b]]");
```

The assembly with the `otherNamespace` is also not referenced and therefore the `GetType` method returns `null`. My question now is:

Is it possible to get the type of an object list which contains another type of an unreferenced assembly? Or: How can I load the assembly of a type within my `ObjectList`?

Comment: I assume Objectlist`1 referring to a generic class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is a little hard for me to test - but I hope my answer can be converted:

basically, you need to do it in two steps -

1. resolve the generic parameter type (myAssembly.otherNamespace.myClass, in your case)
2. generate the new type, based on type of the generic parameter.

Here's a Linqpad script:

```
void Main()
{
    //resolve the inner type
    var  parameterType = Type.GetType("UserQuery+GenericParameter");

    //Use the generic type, and generate with the inner parameter type
    var genericTypeWithParameter = Type.GetType("UserQuery+Moop`1")
        .MakeGenericType(parameterType);

    //The resolved type - printed to console
    genericTypeWithParameter.Dump();
}

public class Moop <T> { }
public class GenericParameter { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but when I try this:

```
public class Moop<T> {}
```

And I do:

```
Type.GetType("UserQuery.Moop`1") //returns null

Type.GetType("UserQuery+Moop`1") //returns the correct type
```

In Linqpad

EDIT: The '+' means it's just a nested type - so, this probably isn't the correct answer.

Comment: You get + when it is a nested type, fairly unlikely in the OP's case.

Comment: I tried it with the '+' but unfortunately it didn't work, `GetType` returns still `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If assembly *myAssembly.otherNamespace.dll* is not in the same directory as executable or installed in GAC, common language runtime cannot locate it. Therefore *myAssembly.otherNamespace.dll* is not loaded to AppDomain and you cannot get type you want.

Put both *myAssembly.Data.DomainObjects.dll* and *myAssembly.otherNamespace.dll* to the same directory where executable file is or install them to GAC. Then use [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx) (instead of [LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx)) to make sure you load them to the same [*Load Cntext*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx).

If metadata in assembly *myAssembly.Data.DomainObjects.dll* contains reference to assembly *myAssembly.otherNamespace.dll*, the latter should be loaded automatically when you load the former. Otherwise you have to load both assemblies before you get type you want.