# What's the order of executables looking for DLLs?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In what order are locations searched to load referenced DLLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972/in-what-order-are-locations-searched-to-load-referenced-dlls)

I have an executable foo.exe which references bar.dll. I have to put bar.dll in the same folder as where foo.exe is or put bar.dll in the GAC. I was wondering if I can put bar.dll in another directory(say bin directory) and ask foo.exe to look for dlls in that directory?

Also, what's the order foo.exe looks for dlls? Current folder first? then GAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to handle [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event if your assemblies are neither in the GAC or the local directory.

Answer (score 0):

yes , you can do even if you can host it in a remote location while in probing phase runtime will try to find it. Searh for assembly Probing