# Is the GAC checked before the file system for non "strong named" assembly references?

Tags: .net, assemblies, gac, strongname

Given

- we have a reference to a not strong named assembly
- a non strong named version of that existing in the bin directory of an app.
- a strong named version of that assembly with same version number installed in the GAC

When that assembly is loaded will we get the on from the filesystem or the one from the GAC?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972/in-what-order-are-locations-searched-to-load-referenced-dlls

Comment: @marceln diff scenario. that answer doesnt address the "non strong named reference" case

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the assembly probing path has not been altered in the configuration, the assembly located in your application's directory will be loaded.

Comment: so did u end up checking? do u have a reference for that?