# XSP4 not running on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: monodevelop, xsp, xsp4

I started to use MonoDevelop 5.0.1 and XSP4 on ubuntu 12.04,When I try to run XSP4  give me this error
I install Monodevelop from ubuntu software center.its running but.I want to run ASP.Net MVC3 application.
AnyBody know this error?

```
Handling exception type FileNotFoundException
Message is Could not load file or assembly 'xsp4, Version=3.0.0.0,                          Culture=neutral,         PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
IsTerminating is set to True
Could not load file or assembly 'xsp4, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap   (string,string)
 at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean quiet) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load   file   or assembly 'xsp4, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,                                              PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
 File name: 'xsp4, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap           (string,string)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean quiet) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, i had the same message (on Calculate Linux with Monodevelop 5.0.1).

you should help it to locate the assembly.

[Either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972/in-what-order-are-locations-searched-to-load-referenced-dlls) place the assembly into GAC with "gacutil -i" or make symlink for bin folder with

```
ln -s . ./bin
```

in the directory of xsp4 binary (it is under ./bin/Debug if you just built it).

to understand it deeper you can [instead of using fuslogvw](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/assembly-bind-tracking-td1505796.html) do this:

1) Run with the environment variables MONO_LOG_LEVEL=info and
MONO_LOG_MASK=asm set, e.g.

```
MONO_LOG_LEVEL=info MONO_LOG_MASK=asm mono yourapp.exe
```

The assembly probing and related logic will be printed to stdout.

2) See the mono(1) man page for more information.