# Cannot access third-party DLL from my.exe

Tags: c#

The scenario:
I use a class from `C:\3rd\dll\thirdparty.dll` in my project by Referencing the location. Building the project I get no errors. The Build result is c:\myprojects\test\my.exe

Now When I run the my.exe I get error:

> Can not find the thirdparty.dll file.

I have updated the PC PATH to include `C:\3rd\dll` folder

Comment: @Sinatr PATH is [not used for .NET references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50058/11683).

Comment: Check if your dll exist in same folder as your exe.

Comment: IF the dll is in the same folder, all works fine. The issue is if it is not in the same folder as my.exe

Comment: @GSerg, I've thought about that for a moment, but couldn't find the reference. Thanks. Then you can basically write the answer. Because it's not possible to have dll in some other folder, only same folders or GAC works.. right?

Comment: @Sem, it's probably not. Why would OP try to include into `Path`? Because it's in other folder. Setting "copy to output folder" (isn't it on by default?) and ensuring it's distributed together with exe is probably what OP doesn't know.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried with copying the dll to the same folder as my.exe

But the issue is that if the thirdparty.dll is changed by the supplier I have to make sure to copy it to my.exe folder. 

I am trying to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) only works for native code. You are using a managed assembly, here is how lookup works for .NET: [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies)